# Can't select (Most) of my armature

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

So I have an interesting situation I have been unable to find an answer for anywhere. I recently started working on a character for an animation. I am ready to start animating, but for some strange reason, I can only select 1-2 of the bones in the armature, in any mode (pose, object, edit, etc.). The "A" command works no problem, but I'm not wanting to select all the bones. Has anyone else come across a situation such as this? One thing I will point out is that occasionally I will see  one bone with a thicker black outline than the others. Idk if this has anything to do with it, but here is a screenshot showing what I mean:

[image]

The bone in question is the one at the base of the spine, which also happens to be one of the few bones I can select. Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I went and updated my Blender Version, and it seems to have solved my problem (Heads up to anybody who sees this, 2.8 is close to being stabilized, so if you haven't already, update your version).